# xargs: unterminated string error - How to go around files with illegal characters?

Tags: character, xargs

I'm writing a one-liner to go through all sub-folders under my current folder "A", get the list of files then search for those files in my other folder "B".  If the file is found then this file is deleted from "A".  All works well until I hit those files with illegal characters.  The command quits with xargs: unterminated string.

```
ls -R * | xargs -I{} find /my/otherfolder/B -type f -name {} -exec rm -f {} \;
```

I tried putting quotes here and there - no luck.  Does anyone know how to get around this one??

Answer (score 2):

Got the same error, but slightly different command. 
For me it worked something like that:

```
find . -type f -name "*php" -print0| xargs -0 grep -sli stringtofind
```

It didn't work until I used `-print0` and `-0` options.

Hope that helps.